# How to check if a data is in gaussian distribution in R or excel?

Tags: r, visualization, gaussian, distribution

I know about the `fitdist()` function from the `fitdistrplus` package in R, however, I am not able to use it to predict a gaussian distribution. I can predict normal, logistic, weibull etc. 
How can I use it for gaussian? are there any other ways to predict this?

Comment: If you can do "normal" you can do "Gaussian". They're the same thing. And where does `fitdist` come from? Its not in the base R packages. Always specify packages if mentioning an R function *not* in the base.

Comment: This is what I am using to test the distribution type:
fit.norm <- fitdist(a$Hours, "norm")
This tells me its not normal, so probably its not gaussian as well. 
How to figure out what distribution it is?

Comment: I get: `Error: object 'fitdist' not found`. There is no such function. Edit your question and put the exact R code, from a clean session, into it.

Comment: you would need to install the package "fitdistrplus" to use the function

Comment: The `fitdist` function in that package doesn't do any goodness-of-fit test, it just fits the parameters of whatever model you ask it to. How does it "tell you" something is "not normal" like you claim in your comment? Again, paste the output from `fitdist` into your question.

Comment: This is what I am currently doing. kstest output says that this distribution is not normal:
"fit.norm <- fitdist(a$$Hours, "norm")"
"fw<-gofstat(fit.norm)"
"fw$kstest"

Comment: You've got two $$ signs in there - please cut and paste *working* code into your answer when you try and illustrate things. Otherwise we can have no confidence in what you are saying. Cut and paste the code and the output.

Comment: Anyway, this is all irrelevant to your question. Normal and Gaussian are the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

The minimum syntax you can use is:

> fit.norm <- fitdist(x, "norm")

to fit the normal density function to the data **x**.

Use the parameters "gamma", "weibull", "lnorm" for fitting gamma, weibull and lognormal  distributions respectively.

After doing that, you can use `plot()` function on your object *fit.norm* to visualize the fitted distribution ,q-q plot, p-p plot and empirical and theoretical CDF's.

Normal distribution and Gaussian distribution are one and the same.

The following is the output due to `plot()` function on the object generated by `fitdist()` function for 1000 standard normal variates.
[image]

Comment: `fitdist(runif(100),"pnorm")` gives "Error in fitdist(runif(100), "pnorm") :  The  dpnorm  function must be defined". You didn't even try this. The second argument of `fitdist` has to be `"norm"` here, not `"pnorm"` or `"qnorm"`.

Comment: While presenting, I made a mistake. You are right.

Comment: @Spacedman I have corrected the typo. I observed that `dnorm` (without quotes) is same as "norm".

Comment: @Spacedman Is there a function called dpnorm?

Comment: No. It takes the string you give it, sticks "d" on the start, and looks for a function of that name to return a density. So if you can write the density, distribution, and quantile functions `dfoo`, `pfoo`, and `qfoo` for the fictonal `foo` distribution, then `fitdist` can act as a framework to fit parameters.

Comment: Using `dnorm` works because the code, if you give it something that isn't a string, gets the name you passed and chops a letter off it via `substring(as.character(match.call()$distr),2)`. This seems to be undocumented and ill-advised. Use the name of the distribution in quotes. All the examples in the documentation use a name in quotes.

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you for your comments. I appreciate your advice. Is the current version ok.? If not kindly suggest improvements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48292/discussion-between-l-v-rao-and-spacedman).

Answer (score 2):

The Normal distribution is the same as the Gaussian distribution. Its just two names for the same thing. Whatever you do - fit parameters, compute goodness-of-fit, etc - if the documentation says its for a Normal distribution then you can say "Gaussian" instead. Completely and totally identical.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by predicting Gaussian/normal distribution.

If you want to check the fit, then you can estimate **mean** and standard **deviation** of your sample and plot two **histograms**: one for your sample and second after generating a sample Gaussian distribution with the mean and standard deviation. By comparing the two you can roughly "see" the fit.

Comment: Have you missed the point about Gaussian and normal distributions being the same?

Comment: No, I did not. I know its the same. Its a simple trick to compare a sample distribution with a known (normal aka Gaussian) one (if mean and std are known).